# Use of present perfect after past simple as clauses of the same sentence

Tags: tenses, past-tense, perfect-aspect

Here is the thing I've written lately. Now, when I look at it, I'm not sure whether this is the right (*natural, basically*) way to put things.

> This post was written about a year ago, but it has been long forgotten among the drafts, as I haven't been frequent guest here lately.

I'm not so sure about the use of tenses. The first clause was in Perfect too before, but I've changed it to Past to comply with basic tense rules at least virtually.

Comment: 'Long forgotten among the drafts' sounds rather poetic; 'long lost among the drafts, and hence of course forgotten' is more literal. 'This post was written about a year ago, but as I haven't been **a** frequent guest here lately, it has been long lost among the drafts, and hence, of course, forgotten.'

Comment: Hah! Perhaps I should abandon the medium so philistine as blogging and immerse myself into poetry. Thank you for your suggestion, kind sir. Would you care to add this as an answer, so it could be approved upon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Long forgotten among the drafts' sounds rather poetic, especially without the 'lying'; 'long lost among the drafts, and hence of course forgotten' is more literal.

More prosaically:

> 'This post was written about a year ago, but as I haven't been a
>   frequent guest here lately, it has been long lost among the drafts,
>   and hence, of course, forgotten.'